# Using Curl with Json (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, curl, json-rpc

I am having trouble getting `curl` and `Json` (`Node.js`) to work when I in `curl` omit the "[ and ]" part of the `JSON-RPC` request params. I am using named parameters (i.e. an object, not an array).

This works:

```
curl -v -i POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"registerPerson", "params": ["{\"username\":\"morten10\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}"], "id":1 }' \
http://localhost:3000
```

However, when I omit the [" and ]" from the params it doesn't work:

```
curl -v -i POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"registerPerson", "params": {\"username\":\"morten10\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}, "id":1 }' \
http://localhost:3000
```

and Jayson gives this error message:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

However, according to the [JSON-RPC 2.0](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) specification and its examples, I should be able to exclude the "[ and ]" part from params when I use named parameters, as in this example:

```
--> {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": {"minuend": 42, "subtrahend": 23}, "id": 4}
<-- {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 19, "id": 4}
```

What am I not getting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your object needs to be a string as suggested by the error.

Try:

```
curl -v -i POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"registerPerson", "params": "{\"username\":\"morten10\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}", "id":1 }' \
http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already. But changing to:

`curl -v -i POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"registerPerson", "params": "{\"username\":\"morten10\",\"password\":\"mypass\"}", "id":1 }' http://localhost:3000`

makes Jayson give this message (before my code is reached):

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid request"}}`

Go figure.

Comment: It is interesting to note that Jayson sets the "id" to null in that error response. According to the JSON-RPC 2.0 specification the "id" must be null only if there is an error detecting the "id" in the request. So, apparently Jayson cannot even locate the "id" in the request. Weird. Assuming Jayson is not buggy, I am guessing it is a quote-escape issue  somehow, but I fail to see what is wrong in that request.

Comment: the only other thing I could suggest is putting it through a linter to see if that will help you figure it out, I notice removing the outer single quotes will allow it to pass on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) for example.

Comment: yes, it should work, also according to the jsonlint.com. I have now filed a bug report with Jayson on GitHub, here: https://github.com/tedeh/jayson/issues/87. Thanks for the help, Brian :)